# Replacing pendant light but reusing existing chock (UK)

Tags: light-fixture

Firstly a disclaimer: I'm new to electrics in general so apologies if I'm using the wrong terminology.

I have a new pendant light from IKEA and it looked like a very straightforward installation. It has connections for a live and a neutral wire, and needs a small hook to hang off.

Having taken my existing light rose off, I have 9 wires coming through the ceiling. I have attached a picture of the configuration.

Having browsed this site I think I understand how the setup works. As I understand it I need a chock and that it can be inside the ceiling or outside under the rose as pictured.

My question is: can I just cut the 2 existing pendant wires, right above the white housing and use these two wires to attach my new pendant?

The new pendant rose fits over the transparent plastic in the picture. I would then add the hook next to the ceiling hole.

Any advice, much appreciated!!

[image: existing configuration]

Comment: I'm confused as to why you'd want to cut the existing pendant wires and try to join the new one onto the cut ends, instead of just unscrewing the old ones from the terminal blocks and attaching your new wires where the old ones were .. ?

Comment: Oh sure, that would be fine too. I just don't have any other wires - the new light only has connections for existing wires

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use choc block (connector strip) inside the ceiling void or externally not covered by a ceiling rose.

If you want to remove the existing rose entirely I would suggest one of these

https://www.tlc-direct.co.uk/Products/TLCT101C.html

which will take the three existing cables on the 'socket' part, provides a loop terminal for the live (the 3 brown wires) and the 'plug' part will connect to your new pendant (live, neutral and earth if needed). It has cable clamps on all the cables and can safely be poked back inside the ceiling void.

Alternative is to remove the ceiling rose, hook and connector strip off the ikea pendant and wire it into the existing ceiling rose, threading the flex through the white rose cover before connecting, then screwing on the rose cover.

For anyone not familiar with UK loop-in wiring, the top 3 blue wires are neutral, the middle 3 brown wires are live, and the bottom pair is (blue sleeved brown) switched live and (brown) live to the pendant.

Comment: Thanks! I went with option 2 and it works great!